# Number Theory and Linear Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

If the equation $$9x + 13y = K$$, has exactly five solutions, where x and y are positive integers, what is the minimum possible value of K?

My work till now has been really simple : $$\frac{(K-13y)}{9} = x$$

Now I understand x should be an integer so $$K-13y$$ should be a multiple of 9.

Can't seem to get beyond this.

All help is appreciated

Comment: Maybe consider the case where $K$ gives rise to only one solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X, Y$ be an integer solution pair of $9x + 13y = K$, with $X, Y$ not necessarily positive.

Then other integer solutions are given by 
$$x = X - 13j, \quad y = Y + 9j$$
where $j$ is any integer,

since
$$9(X - 13j) + 13(Y + 9j) = 9X - 9.13j + 13Y + 9.13j = 9X + 13Y = K$$

It can be shown that this gives *all* integer solutions because $\gcd(13, 9) = 1$.

To restrict $x$ and $y$ to positive integers, we need

$X - 13j > 0$ and $Y + 9j > 0$

to both be true simultaneously.

$$
X > 13j\\
j < \frac{X}{13}\\
- Y < 9j\\
\frac{-Y}{9} < j\\
\frac{-Y}{9} < j < \frac{X}{13}
$$
If that last inequality is only satisfied by a single integer $j$ then there will be a single solution to $9x + 13y = K$ with both $x, y > 0$.

To find $n+1$ positive solutions we need
$$\frac{-Y}{9} < j, \quad j + n < \frac{X}{13}$$
since there are $n+1$ elements in the set $\lbrace j,\cdots, j+n\rbrace$.

To find the smallest $K$ with $n+1$ positive solutions we need to make those fractions as close to integers as possible, so $\frac{-Y}{9} + \frac{1}{9}$ and $\frac{X}{13} - \frac{1}{13}$ need to be integers.

i.e.,
$$\frac{-Y+1}{9} = j$$
and
$$ j + n = \frac{X-1}{13}$$
Multiplying both equations by $9.13 = 117$,
$$
13(-Y+1) = 117j\\
-13Y + 13 = 117j\\
117(j + n) = 9(X-1)\\
117j + 117n = 9X-9\\
117j = 9X-9 - 117n\\
-13Y + 13 = 9X - 9 - 117n\\
117n + 13 + 9 = 9X + 13Y\\
117n + 22 = 9X + 13Y = K\\
$$
So 
$$117n + 22 = K$$
Gives us the smallest $K$ that has $n+1$ solutions.

When $n=0$, we get one solution for $K=22$:
$9.1 + 13.1 = 22$

For $n=1$, we get two solutions for $K=139$:
$9.14 + 13.1 = 9.1 + 13.10 = 139$

For $n=2$, the 3 solutions are
$9.27 + 13.1 = 9.14 + 13.10 = 9.1 + 13.19 = 256$

For $n=3$, the 4 solutions are
$9.40 + 13.1 = 9.27 + 13.10 = 9.14 + 13.19 = 9.1 + 13.28 = 373$

And for $n=4$, the 5 solutions are
$9.53 + 13.1 = 9.40 + 13.10 = 9.27 + 13.19 = 9.14 + 13.28 = 9.1 + 13.37 = 490$